# Delete Buttons with list items

Tags: jquery

I can't tell what is wrong with this jQuery code. I'm receiving no errors from the debugger. I'm at a lost with what is wrong.

```
<ul id="list"></ul>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#show_place_on_screen').click(function () {

var address = $('#address').val();

$("#list").append('<li>' + address + '<input type="button"   

id="delete" value="Delete"/></li>');

});

$("#delete").click(function() { 

    $(this).parent().remove();

});});

</script>
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: The line break after "button" is a problem.

Comment: There was no error message. The line break does not exist in the code. I placed it in the post on here for easy viewing.

Comment: can you make a demo at jsfiddle.net so that we can work on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delegate the `click` event, also you can use classes, IDs must be unique:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show_place_on_screen').click(function() {
        var address = $('#address').val();
        $("#list").append('<li>'+address+'<input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete"/></li>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you append to the list, you are giving each button the same `id`. If more than one element in the DOM has the same `id`, your click handler targetting that `id` will probably break.

Try:

```
$("#list").append('<li>' + address + '<input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete"/></li>');
```

And:

```
$(".delete").live('click', function() { 
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Also, you better hope `address` doesn't contain any nasty code that could be interpretted as HTML. You should probably escape it.

Answer (score 0):

how about trying

> bind('click', function(){})

instead of the current  `.click(function() {....`

as these elements are auto generated, by some jquery code

hope this helps